# How to resize my imported external swf file to fit(fullscreen) into stage? please give some sample codes

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I used this code to import my swf file.now I want my swf file to fill all my stage(fullscreen).please give some sample code.

```
import flash.display.Loader; 
import flash.display.Sprite; 
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.StageScaleMode;

var ldr:Loader = new Loader(); 
var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest("File/game.swf"); 
ldr.load(urlReq); 
ldr.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaded); 
addChild(ldr); 

function loaded(event:Event):void 
{ 
var content:Sprite = event.target.content; 
content.scaleX = 1 ; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will stretch the loaded swf to fill the stage:

```
function loaded(event:Event):void 
{ 
    var content:Sprite = event.target.content; 
    content.scaleX = stage.stageWidth/content.width;
    content.scaleY = stage.stageHeight/content.height;
}
```

Comment: how does it not fit in stage? too big? too small?